# window location href not reloading

Tags: javascript

I am working with javascript and php, and I want to send variables from an html file to a php file continuously, but the method window.location.href only send it one time, despite I call the function every second. How do I keep sending data continuously using window.location.href?

HTML file:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="zepto.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
       function refresh() {
        var wind = 255;
        var rain = 1;
        var speed = 56;

        window.location.href = "http://localhost/getData.php?s1=" + wind +"&s2=" + rain + "&s3=" + speed;

    }

 </script>
</head>
<body onload="setInterval(refresh, 1000);">
</body>
```

Comment: That's not... That's a redirect, not a reload. Either way it stops any JavaScript from running...

Comment: I also already try using other ways like reload(), or assign(), in conditions using if and while statements, but unsuccessful.

Comment: That's not how you want to do it, use AJAX for that.

Answer (score 0):

when you use `window.location.href = 'http://somewhere`, the browser looses context and your variables are lost.

a smarter way to keep sending variables to your server is by using the [ajax function of zepto or jquery](http://zeptojs.com/#$.get)

```
$.get("http://localhost/getData.php?s1=" + wind +"&s2=" + rain + "&s3=" + speed", function(){
    console.log('server received information');
})
```

Comment: Using that function does not work, I dont know why. I try this instead and does not work indeer:                                                                                                                                                                     `$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'http://localhost/getData.php',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: ({s1: wind, s2: rain, s3: speed}),
                    success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                    }
                });`

Comment: is your server receiving a connection? what does the dev-tools say?

Comment: Is not receiving, but using ajax request, do I need to have javascript code in my php file to receive data?

Comment: no, javascript needs to be in the html, your php script sends to the browser. in our php script, you should have a $_POST/$_GET variable where the sent information is held.